How can I parse a bunch of rectangles as a table structure and put it into csv
I was able to extract a bunch of rectangles from a table using opencv.

Now, I would like to parse these rectangles as a table structure. I could just iterate over the rectangles and put them into a CSV by sorting them with their x and y coordinates
I face two issues while doing so:

The rectangles need not be aligned appropriately, i.e. rectangles on the same horizontal row may have different x coordinates
As you can see, some rectangles might span three columns or even more, it can also be the case that some rectangles span three rows. How do I identify this and have the text in the large spanning rectangle be representative for all the rows/columns they cover.

Any ideas of how this could be approached would be appreciated.
This is what I am extracting these rectangles from:


Is the example image representative of what you are parsing (i.e. will boxes be touching with no black-space in between, and will there boxes be aligned along the same y-coordinates?)

You are asking for suggestions without providing code nor unprocessed images. Both are off topic. Also, given the way this question is presented, it's surprising to see that it already has 2 upvotes.

@AndrewRyan  The boxes need not be aligned along the same y-coordinates (just slightly off with each other). However, the boxes seem to touch in this image due to the line width. They do not actually touch.

@stateMachine Please find the neccessary changes above

@Spongerooski this is the third time you post almost the same question

@TinoD this question is different from my last two questions which were mutually different too. In this question, I was able to extract rectangles but now ask about how I should identify which column/ row they belong to

@Spongerooski you ignored my almost, but fine. I'll bite, use the center of each identified box as a key identifier, you can round up or down to the nearest multiple of 5 or 10. Sorting them will also be quite easy. For the wide boxs, it's not possible to assign more than one field to a nunber, so you'll have to skip fields. Hint: if you're satisfied with the answers given to Q#2, accept one of them to close the question.

@TinoD Could you please elaborate more on how I should handle the wide boxes

@Spongerooski since you have the boxes, check their widths, if almost a multiple of 2, then skip one field, if almost a multiple of 3, then skip two fields, etc. Can't really put a useful answer for you, 'tis the season after all
